# Can't set up public key ssh authentication

Tags: logging, sshd

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04. I'm trying to setup ssh public key authentication. Unfortunately, it refuses to work. Running the ssh client in verbose mode I can see that the public keys are being refused.

`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` exists and seems to have the correct permissions etc.

What I would like to do is to read the sshd log to find out what it is complaining about. But I cannot find where the sshd logs to on Ubuntu 12.04. I've tried googling and checked /var/log/auth.log and /var/log/syslog and neither are showing sshd messages. Where can I find the daemon logs to figure out what is going on?

```
sshd is set with logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

and /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf reads:

```
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
```

but nothing shows up about sshd in those log files.

Also. No sshd process appears to be running if run ps xa | grep sshd. Is that normal? It certainly accepts password connections.

Comment: It is unclear to me if you are trying to setup SSH server on your machine, or you are trying to connect to remote machine using your private key?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I'm trying to setup my machine as a ssh server. For testing I'm using this machine as server and client (i.e ssh localhost) which works when a password is provided, but I need key-based authentication.

Comment: I see. Well, if password works, then sshd is installed and works. Does the log at /var/log/auth.log say something when you connect via password? When you specify wrong password?

Comment: No. No sshd logs show up in auth.log or anywhere else that I've looked.

Comment: My kneejerk reaction was that you must be connecting to the wrong machine, but if you're connecting to localhost, that's not very likely. Still, post the output of `ssh -vv localhost`, and of `netstat -lnt`. Do you have any virtualization going on? Any chroot?

Comment: ssh -vv shows the publickey login being attempt at netstat -lnt includes the line:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: I just don't understand what I've done wrong. This is a fresh Ubuntu install I did apt-get install openssh.

Comment: I tried running sshd -p 2222 -d as root and this works fine (i.e. allows public key login) after I create the directory /var/run/ssh . Rebooting seems to erase this directory. This makes me think that the problem has nothing to do with the permissions on key files.

Comment: @Gilles no chroot - unless the default Ubuntu install does something weird.

Comment: Do you still have the problem after rebooting? Please post your complete `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, too. Did you change it from the default? And please run `netstat -lntp` (I forgot the `p` earlier) and run `ps l` on the process listening on port 22 to see what it is.

Comment: sshd_config http://pastebin.com/L3vb32BU

Comment: Ah ok. Something is starting to make sense! netstat -lntp shows:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1026/lshd

which means lshd is answering port 22. I'm guessing thats part of the problem

Comment: $ps l

ps l
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000  2324  2278  20   0  27956  5072 wait   Ss   pts/1      0:00 bash
0  1000  3629  2324  20   0  41444  2996 poll_s S+   pts/1      0:00 ssh localhost
4  1000  3631  1026  20   0  24844  8892 wait   Ss   pts/3      0:00 -bash
0  1000  6256  2278  20   0  27908  5024 n_tty_ Ss+  pts/2      0:00 bash
0  1000 30367  3631  20   0   6840   784 -      R+   pts/3      0:00 ps l

Comment: so it seems lshd is answering port 22 and sshd never runs (/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run exists). Is lshd the standard ubuntu ssh server now? Which is recommended. I really just want a stock setup but lshd doesn't seem to like my public key system.

Answer (score 2):

OP answered:

> In case anyone encounters this in future. For me the problem was solved by realising that lshd rather the opensshd was answering port 22. Removing lshd (apt-get remove lsh-server) fixed everything.
>
> Thanks to @Gilles for pointing me in the right direction.